# converting POSIXct back to factor

Tags: r, posixct

I have converted a list of times into POSIXct format, and now I need to convert them back to factor, but I am not able to. How can I resolve this ?

```
> data
[1] "2015-12-01 09:14:24 EST" "2015-12-01 17:51:47 EST" "2015-12-02 08:50:52 EST" "2015-12-02 09:38:45 EST"
[5] "2015-12-06 02:30:46 EST" "2015-12-06 14:02:22 EST"

> as.factor(data)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Comment: This works.. `factor(as.POSIXct("2015-12-01 09:14:24 EST"))`. Can you supply `dput(head(data))` in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because the OP have a `POSIXlt` class object.  It is a `list` and calling `factor` will result in error

```
 as.factor(as.POSIXlt(v1))
 #Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
 #Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

But, if it is `POSIXct` object, it works

```
as.factor(as.POSIXct(v1))
#[1] 2015-12-01 09:14:24
#Levels: 2015-12-01 09:14:24
```

We can convert it to `POSIXct` and then it should work

```
as.factor(as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(v1)))
#[1] 2015-12-01 09:14:24
#Levels: 2015-12-01 09:14:24
```

We can check the `class` by either using `class` or `str`

```
class(as.POSIXct(v1))
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
class(as.POSIXlt(v1))
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- "2015-12-01 09:14:24"
```